# How much data to receive from server in SSL handshake before calling InitializeSecurityContext?

Tags: sspi

In our Windows C++ application I am using InitializeSecurityContext() client side to open an schannel connection to a server which is running stunnel SSL proxy.  My code now works, but only with a hack I would like to eliminate.

I started with this sample code:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380536%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

In the sample code, look at SendMsg and ReceiveMsg.  The first 4 bytes of any message sent or received indicates the message length.  This is fine for the sample, where the server portion of the sample conforms to the same convention.

stunnel does not seem to use this convention.  When the client is receiving data during the handshake, how does it know when to stop receiving and make another call to InitializeSecurityContext()?

This is how I structured my code, based on what I could glean from the documentation:

```
1. call InitializeSecurityContext which returns an output buffer
2. Send output buffer to server
3. Receive response from server
4. call InitializeSecurityContext(server_response) which returns an output buffer
5. if SEC_E_INCOMPLETE_MESSAGE, go back to step 3, 
   if SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED go back to step 2
```

I expected InitializeSecurityContext in step 4 to return SEC_E_INCOMPLETE_MESSAGE if not enough data was read from the server in step 3.  Instead, I get SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED but an empty output buffer.  I have experimented with a few ways to handle this case (e.g. go back to step 3), but none seemed to work and more importantly, I do not see this behavior documented.

In step 3 if I add a loop that receives data until a timeout expires, everything works fine in my test environment.  But there must be a more reliable way.

What is the right way to know how much data to receive in step 3?

Answer (score 4):

SChannel is different than the Negotiate security package. You need to receive at least 5 bytes, which is the SSL/TLS record header size:

```
struct {
    ContentType type;
    ProtocolVersion version;
    uint16 length;
    opaque fragment[TLSPlaintext.length];
} TLSPlaintext;
```

ContentType is 1 byte, ProtocolVersion is 2 bytes, and you have 2 byte record length. Once you read those 5 bytes, SChannel will return SEC_E_INCOMPLETE_MESSAGE and will tell you exactly how many more bytes to expect:

```
SEC_E_INCOMPLETE_MESSAGE
Data for the whole message was not read from the wire.

When this value is returned, the pInput buffer contains a SecBuffer structure with a BufferType member of SECBUFFER_MISSING. The cbBuffer member of SecBuffer contains a value that indicates the number of additional bytes that the function must read from the client before this function succeeds.
```

Once you get this output, you know exactly how much to read from the network.

Comment: Thanks - the problem was I was not getting SEC_E_INCOMPLETE_MESSAGE as I expected.  I first tried parsing the ssl handshake messages and reading until all expected data was received (eg. ServerHelloDone) before calling InitializeSecurityContext.  This worked, but I was not happy with this solution.  I found the problem:

I found this sample:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/sslsocket.aspx 

I was missing the handling of SECBUFFER_EXTRA (line 987 SslSocket.cpp)

Comment: Yes, you do nee the extra buffer in case there is extraneous data, which you need to supply in subsequent calls. Keep in mind that if you get SEC_E_OK with extra data, you need to pass the extra data to DecryptMessage, as it will contain application data.

Comment: @Nasko +1. **Finally, a clear answer on SChannel.** Reading pages and pages of docs and your answer made me click!

Comment: I found that `SEC_E_INCOMPLETE_MESSAGE` returned as a result to `InitializeSecurityContext` did *not* return any extra buffer or indicator of missing data. But unconditionally reading more when getting that return code worked.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.

I found this sample:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/sslsocket.aspx

I was missing the handling of SECBUFFER_EXTRA (line 987 SslSocket.cpp)

Answer (score 1):

The SChannel SSP returns `SEC_E_INCOMPLETE_MESSAGE` from both `InitializeSecurityContext` and `DecryptMessage` when not enough data is read.

A `SECBUFFER_MISSING` message type is returned from `DecryptMessage` with a `cbBuffer` value of the amount of desired bytes.

But in practice, I did not use the "missing data" value. The documentation indicates the value is not guaranteed to be correct, and is only a hint for developers can use to reduce calls.

InitalizeSecurityContext [MSDN doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375924%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> While this number is not always accurate, using it can help improve performance by avoiding multiple calls to this function.

So I unconditionally read more data into the same buffer whenever `SEC_E_INCOMPLETE_MESSAGE` was returned. Reading multiple bytes at a time from a socket.

Some extra input buffer management was required to append more read data and keep the lengths right. `DecryptMessage` will modify the input buffers' `cbBuffer` properties when it fails, which surprised me.

Printing out the buffers and return result after calling `InitializeSecurityContext` shows the following:

```
read socket:bytes(5).
InitializeSecurityContext:result(80090318). // SEC_E_INCOMPLETE_MESSAGE
inBuffers[0]:type(2),bytes(5).
inBuffers[1]:type(0),bytes(0).   // no indication of missing data
outBuffer[0]:type(2),bytes(0).

read socket:bytes(74).
InitializeSecurityContext:result(00090312). // SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED
inBuffers[0]:type(2),bytes(79).  // notice 74 + 5 from before
inBuffers[1]:type(0),bytes(0).
outBuffer[0]:type(2),bytes(0).
```

And for the `DecryptMessage` Function, input is always in `dataBuf[0]`, with the rest zeroed.

```
read socket:bytes(5).
DecryptMessage:len 5, bytes(17030201). // SEC_E_INCOMPLETE_MESSAGE
DecryptMessage:dataBuf[0].BufferType 4, 8  // notice input buffer modified
DecryptMessage:dataBuf[1].BufferType 4, 8
DecryptMessage:dataBuf[2].BufferType 0, 0
DecryptMessage:dataBuf[3].BufferType 0, 0

read socket:bytes(8).
DecryptMessage:len 13, bytes(17030201). // SEC_E_INCOMPLETE_MESSAGE
DecryptMessage:dataBuf[0].BufferType 4, 256
DecryptMessage:dataBuf[1].BufferType 4, 256
DecryptMessage:dataBuf[2].BufferType 0, 0
DecryptMessage:dataBuf[3].BufferType 0, 0

read socket:bytes(256).
DecryptMessage:len 269, bytes(17030201). // SEC_E_OK
```

We can see my TLS Server peer is sending TLS headers (5 bytes) in one packet, and then the TLS message (8 for Application Data), then the Application Data payload in a third.

Answer (score 1):

You must read some arbitrary amount the first time, and when you receive `SEC_E_INCOMPLETE_MESSAGE`, you must look in the `pInput SecBufferDesc` for a `SECBUFFER_MISSING` and read its `cbBuffer` to find out how many bytes you are missing.

This problem was doing my head in today, as I was attempting to modify my handshake myself, *and* having the same problem the other commenters were having, i.e. not finding a `SECBUFFER_MISSING`. I do *not* want to interpret the tls packet myself, and I do *not* want to unconditionally read some unspecified number of bytes. I found the solution to that, so I'm going to address their comments, too.

The confusion here is because the API is confusing. Ordinarily, to read the output of `InitializeSecurityContext`, you look at the content of the `pOutput` parameter (as defined in [the signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/initializesecuritycontext--schannel)). It's *that* `SecBufferDesc` that contains the `SECBUFFER_TOKEN` etc to pass to `AcceptSecurityContext`.

However, in the case where `InitializeSecurityContext` returns `SEC_E_INCOMPLETE_MESSAGE`, the `SECBUFFER_MISSING` is returned in the `pInput SecBufferDesc`, in place of the `SECBUFFER_ALERT SecBuffer` that was passed in.

The documentation *does* say this, but not in a way that clearly contrasts this case against the `SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED` and `SEC_E_OK` cases.

This answer *also* applies to `AcceptSecurityContext`.

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN, I'd presume `SEC_E_INCOMPLETE_MESSAGE` is returned when not enough data is received from server at the moment. Instead, `SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED` returned with `InBuffers[1]` indicating amount of **unread** data (note that some data is processed and must be skipped) and `OutBuffers` containing nothing.

So the algorithm is:

- If `SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED` returned, check type of `InBuffers[1]`
- If it is `SECBUFFER_EXTRA`, handle it (move `InBuffers[1].cbBuffer` bytes to the beginning of input buffer) and jump to next `recv & InitializeSecurityContext` iteration
- If `OutBuffers` is not empty, send its contents to server